# Meteor build error with Cordova for iOS: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: objective-c, meteor

I'm wrote an iOS plugin to send email and sms that imports `<MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>`, but when I add this plugin to my Meteor project and try to execute `meteor run ios` for my project I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EmailComposer.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Sms.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I use this same plugin and build with XCode6, it compiles and links fine. Typically this type of error occurs when you haven't added the Message package, but it's not clear how to do that with Meteor. Perhaps I need to add the Message package like I do in XCode somehow, but I'm unsure how to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in the plugin.xml these important lines were missing:

```
    <framework src="MessageUI.framework" />
    <framework src="MobileCoreServices.framework" />
```